# Error: "uninitialsed local variable 'name' used" in C++ using char *

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I have written this code snippet:

```
int main()
{
    char *name;
    cin >> name;

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it gives error as: "uninitialsed local variable 'name' used". I don't understand why this is happening. Please explain what is my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: `name` is not initialized and you are using it? I don't understand the confusion. Also, this is instant segfault.

Comment: That's not an error. It's a warning, issued by some static code analyzer, maybe your compiler or an external tool. At any rate, the warning text is fairly unambiguous, no?

Comment: `cin >> name` instructs the input stream to read a string and store it at the memory pointed to by `name`.  In your code, `name` doesn't point at any memory.

Comment: Unlike regular variables pointers need to point to something in order to be useful.

Comment: This is clearly C++, not C. ***They are not the same language*** --- please use appropriate tags.

Comment: @DeiDei, You'd hope it's an instant segfault, but in practice, these things can stay quiet until you demo to your boss.

Comment: [Or your boss is showing off the new USB support at ComDex.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjZQGRATlwA)

Comment: @DeiDei It will never give you segfault, unless you try to deference it which might give you then.

Comment: @Harveer -- Writing characters to who-knows-where will never give you a seg fault?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My bad. Missed to see the write operations there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char*` is a pointer to a `char` which, at the moment, doesn't 'point' anywhere. You could allocate some memory and point to that.

```
char* name = new char[64];
cin >> name;
delete[] name;
```

However, you can avoid this requirement by using `std::string`. Have a look at some examples here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you allocate memory for `name` you are writing to an uninitialized pointer.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char *name = new char[100];
    std::cin >> name;
    delete [] name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The wording is misleading. Allocating memory doesn't fix the immediate issue, that a pointer is uninitialized. Assigning a value does (which may or may not require allocating memory).

Comment: If he's trying to write from `std::cin` he needs to allocate memory - if he just assigned a string literal to a `char *` pointer it would be read only memory

Comment: *"If he's trying to write from std::cin he needs to allocate memory"* - No. You need a valid pointer. This does not imply allocating memory, e.g. `char buffer[100]; char* name = &buffer[0];` assigns a valid pointer to `name`, without allocating memory. Assigning a valid value is the key point here.